# Fetch friends data with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

1. I need fetch user's friends data with next fields: id, name,
   gender, birthday, city, country, profileUrl, pic, pic_small,
   pic_big, is_app_user.

   Before I used FB.Data.query, but now it's deprecated.

   ```
    FB.Data.query('select uid, first_name, last_name, name, pic,
     pic_small, pic_big, birthday_date, sex, current_location,
    profile_url, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from
    friend where uid1 = {0}', uid).
   ```
2. How to fetch friends, who are using app?

I can get all fields what i need, but for example for pictures i need to do additional requests. Can i get all needed fields in single request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use same [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query with [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

```
var query = 'SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, name, pic, pic_small, pic_big, birthday_date, sex, current_location, profile_url, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ' + uid;
FB.api('/fql',{q:query}, function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

You for sure can also get almost same data with [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) not using [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) at all:

```
FB.api('/'+uid+'/friends', {
  fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,name,birthday,gender,location,link,installed'
}, function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

You have a bit different names and other format (ex `location`) for those details and miss the picture details in results but this is simple, [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) picture is available on URL in form `http://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture`

> use ?type=square | small | normal | large to request a different photo

Comment: Nope. Only the `FB.Data.*` methods was deprecated, see details on http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/561/

Comment: Thanks a lot. But second variant is not for me, because too many requests. [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/ "FQL") - what do i need

Answer (score 0):

I've been poking around with this too, using PHP. This is what I came up with:

```
$user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=installed');
$user_players = array();
foreach ($user_friends['data'] as $userfriend)
{
    if (array_key_exists('installed', $userfriend))
    {
        array_push($user_players, $userfriend);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The Following Helps you to fetch user's friend details using graph api

NSString friendId =10020020 //Store Friend ID;

NSString * pRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?fields=name,picture,work,hometown,birthday,devices,interests",friendId];


    [[FBRequest requestForGraphPath:pRequestString ] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",result);

    }];
```