# Fetch all friends from my facebook userid and accesstoken

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I want to show all the facebook friends of app user in a table view(Photo,name,userid)
I got the user id and accesstoken of the user..Now how can I fetch the friends list ?

is there any graph api URL ?

Comment: I have tried the login and fetched the access token of user.

Using that access token..I am fetching the friends list with this graph API https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token= But I am not getting the image urls..why ?

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972518/fetch-friends-data-with-graph-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *fields = @"id,name,picture,first_name";
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=%@",fields];
```

Now merge this with your accessToken

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@", path,yourAccessToken]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
You can find the detailed documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends).